# Proper ampersand handling in e-mail activation link

Tags: html, url-parameters

In e-mail activation links I return

```
<a href="http://www.foo.com/register.php?action=activation&key=123">Activation</a>
```

In some clients (e.g. SquirrelMail) `&` is changed to `&amp;` which breaks the link.

```
<a href="http://www.foo.com/register.php?action=activation&amp;key=123">Activation</a>
```

How can I make sure the link is displayed correctly in all e-mail clients?

Comment: `http://www.foo.com/register.php?action=activation&key=123` is invalid HTML. When browsers perform error recovery on it, they turn it into `http://www.foo.com/register.php?action=activation&amp;key=123`. Having the server side software implement that fix before it reached the browser shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: Ah right, the browser correction. I tried &amp; in the adressbar directly where it doesn't work.

Comment: The address bar expects a URL expressed in plain text. URLs in HTML need to be expressed in HTML. `&amp;` is how you say `&` in HTML, so when it gets converted from HTML into a URL it will be `&`.

Comment: It wasn't me creating this. I just wanted be sure before reporting the mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried URL-escaping the ampersand?

```
<a href="http://www.foo.com/register.php?action=activation%26key=123">Activation</a>
```

FWIW, the

```
<a href="http://www.foo.com/register.php?action=activation&key=123">Activation</a>
```

is a perfectly fine bit of HTML data, and i believe your issue is actually showcasing a bug in SquirrelMail.